# CommandNotFound Error when using cogs in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am learning discord.py from a tutorial series on youtube. I was able to progress smoothly until the lesson of Cogs. I tried implementing cogs they way they showed on the tutorial and it didnt work. I tried reading the documentation, checked other sites and still not working.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

rules = ['Users must obey the discord community guidelines.',
         'No racism/homophobia/bullying/etc of any kind Bullying of any kind will end in a mute and possibly a ban.',
         'Everyone Can Report', 'No Server Raiding', 'No Chatting In welcome channel',
         'No robbing and bankrob is illegal', 'No impersonating']

class Greetings(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
    
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_join(member):
        await member.send("Hi there, welcome to the server.")
        await member.send("These are the rules:")
        for x in range(len(rules)):
            await member.send('RULE ' + str(x+1) + ': ' + rules[x])

    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def hi(self,ctx):
        await ctx.send("hi!")

async def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Greetings(client))
```

This is the cog which I kept in a folder named cogs

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os


TOKEN = 'my_token'

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name='a server'))
    print('We have Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

initial_extensions = []

for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        initial_extensions.append("cogs." + filename[:-3])

print(initial_extensions)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for extension in initial_extensions:
        client.load_extension(extension)



client.run(TOKEN)
```

And Here's what is being printed on the console:

```
discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command None
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "hi" is not found
```

It also shows this error:

```
E:\Programming Stuff\Discord Bots\Bot\index.py:28: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.load_extension' was never awaited
  client.load_extension(extension)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

I tried changing it to an async function, but that didnt work as well.

Comment: "*I tried changing it to an async function, but that didn't work as well.*" - What exactly? Your code can be simplified and changed at some places, just want to make sure you already tried to do so yourself?

Comment: I did try out a few changes(but none worked), and I dont get where I can simplify my code? Are u referring to string formatting my print statements? But now my problem is solved, I was following a tutorial from 2021, so yeah some of the code it had was outdated. Thank you for trying to help out tho, this is my first time asking questions on stack overflow, really appreciate you :)

Answer (score 0):

As an extension to the asyncio changes in discord.py v2.0, the loading and unloading of extensions and cogs is now asynchronous ([read more](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#extension-and-cog-loading-unloading-is-now-asynchronous)).
This way you will need to load the extensions in an async context as shown below:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import asyncio


TOKEN = 'my_token'

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name='a server'))
    print('We have Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

initial_extensions = []

for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        initial_extensions.append("cogs." + filename[:-3])
print(initial_extensions)


async def main():
    async with bot:
        for extension in initial_extensions:
            await client.load_extension(extension)
        await client.start(TOKEN)


asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this really worked, was stuck on this problem for the past two days :)